# Different banner for different filter selected on Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, header, banner

I am currently using AngularJs to do the filter of the products. The filter is working fine, except i can't find a solution where, when I select a certain filter not only the contents change but also the header. How do I do that? example website : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsEjr.jpg)

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zoTS.jpg)

[image]

---

```
<div class="sidebar" style="border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;">
  <div ng-repeat="filter in Filters"
       style="border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;">
    <h3 class="sort" style="font-size: 18px;
                            font-weight: 100;
                            text-transform: uppercase;
                            margin-bottom: 15px;"
    >{{filter.name}}</h3>
```

Comment: do I use partial view on angularjs?

Comment: Show us your relevant code so we can look at it.

Comment: <div class="sidebar" style="border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;">
<div ng-repeat="filter in Filters" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;">
<h3 class="sort" style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: 100;text-transform: uppercase;    margin-bottom: 15px;">{{filter.name}}</h3>

Comment: Please put your code in your question, and indent it properly so the code displays properly here.